# How can I remove a subfolder from My Drive without removing it from my collaborators?

Tags: google-drive

Somebody shared a folder with me.

I moved it into "My Drive" to sync it (I should have copied, but I did not know at the time).

Now I want to remove a subfolder of that folder from "My Drive". But if I delete it it will disappear from the collaborators too.

I can't drag it out of "My Drive".

Is there any way to do so?

It's ok if it disappear from the initial folder but can be found at another location - I just want it out of My Drive, because I don't want to sync it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're the "owner" of that subfolder, set the owner as someone else. Then when you delete it it will only be removed from your account; the other people with whom it is shared will still have access to it.

Comment: Thanks Al that's sort of what I thought but I just wasn't sure it would work like that. I'll still make a copy for a first test ;-)

Comment: Always a wise plan.

Answer (score 4):

With the file or folder highlighted,

- Select the information view (black icon with white lower case 'i' in the top right hand of your drive window
- a panel should appear down the right side of your screen
- you'll have two options - 'details' or 'activity'. Select 'details'.
- in this view, you should see 'type', 'location', 'owner' etc... under location will be a list of all folders in which the file/folder lives
- click the 'x' next to the location you want the file/folder 'un-added' from.

If you're doing this clean up within the location you're cleaning, the file will disappear but don't be alarmed! It will still be in all the other locations listed in the information view.

Comment: `click the 'x' next to the location you want the file/folder 'un-added' from.` This no longer exists

Answer (score 0):

Holding ctrl then clicking on the file and dragging to the bin will also remove a file/folder from the location you're viewing without deleting from all other locations.