# Joined a Google group now shared files appears to Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-groups, google-drive-sharing

I recently joined a Google Group and upon joining, several shared files started appearing in my Google Drive.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening without leaving the group?

Comment: They show up under "Shared with me", right?

Comment: @Punchlinern Nope they show up in "All Items". "Shared with me" is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting a shared document will not change your group status. If you no longer wish to receive shared documents then I would suggest talking to your group administrator who may be able to put you in a category of "group member" but exclude you from the "share documents" group. This is completely up to how your group is organized and run though.

When other groups share documents with you they will appear in your *Shared with Me* directory. The only way a shared file can be listed in *My Drive* is if you take the shared document and place it there. Remember, if you placed a *Shared with Me* folder in your *My Drive* all files and subfolders in that file will now be in your *My Drive*.

The *All Items* folder displays all documents in your *My Drive* and *Shared with Me* directories.

If you want to remove a shared document form your *My Drive* directory then [simply delete it](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40384/how-do-i-move-shared-documents-folders-that-i-have-in-my-drive-in-google-apps).

If you want to remove a shared document form your *Shared with Me* directory you can  [simply delete it](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/37349/how-can-i-remove-a-subfolder-from-my-drive-without-removing-it-from-my-collabora).